# How to query authoritative name server to side-step propagation times?

Tags: dns, dig

I have a domain with 123-reg.co.uk and I've created a TXT record:

[image]

I have tried to verify it has been applied by using both the `dig` and `host` shell commands, but it appears the TXT record isn't being found.

For example...

```
host -t txt integralist.co.uk
```

...returns: `integralist.co.uk has no TXT record`

At first I assumed it might be a TTL issue and so I tried to use `dig` to query one of the authoritative name servers directly (thus avoiding a TTL caching concern), like so

```
dig txt integralist.co.uk @ns.123-reg.co.uk.
```

...but this returns no `ANSWER` section.

I'm not sure what I'm missing in order to side step any TTL/propagation issues that might be preventing me from querying an authoritative name server directly and seeing the record.

> Note: It's currently 4pm Mon 12th Oct 2015 and I added the TXT record around 9am this morning, so by the time someone replies any propagation time frame preventing the record from appearing when querying the domain may well have passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS records (contrary to popular belief) don't propagate, they are being cached (and that is why sometimes you have to wait for the cache to expire when you make DNS changes). That being said, when you create a new record there was nothing in the cache to expire, so new records should be visible immediately.

Now, to shed some light on your issue, everything is working exactly as you configured it:

```
 ; <<>> DiG 9 <<>> @8.8.8.8 my-service-description.integralist.co.uk TXT
 ; (1 server found)
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1490
 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;my-service-description.integralist.co.uk. IN TXT

 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
 my-service-description.integralist.co.uk. 14399    IN TXT "integralist.co.uk is a tech blog"

 ;; Query time: 39 msec
 ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
 ;; WHEN: Mon Oct 12 19:48:28 2015
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

Maybe you wanted to create TXT record for the zone apex:

```
@   TXT         "integralist.co.uk is a tech blog"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for confirming. Silly question but what variation of the dig command did you use to get that response?

Comment: BTW: In all the examples I saw everyone used a unique name for the TXT record rather than @ (root/apex). So not sure if that's best practice or not?

Comment: `dig txt my-service-description.integralist.co.uk @8.8.8.8`

Comment: Well, i guess it only depends what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the @8.8.8.8 ? I Google'd and looks like a Google ip but not sure why you're ref that as the authoritative name server?

Comment: Yes, it is google DNS. It is not authoritative for your domain, I've just used it to show that your new txt record is already resolvable even on DNS servers other than your authoritative. You should get similar answer using `dig txt my-service-description.integralist.co.uk @ns.123-reg.co.uk`

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you :-)